# Select Gender Radio Input

Tags: php, html

How can I make my user select with radio buttons between "Male" and "Female" and e.g. When someone select "Male" and has already selected "Female", "Female" get unchecked.

```
<input type="radio" placeholder="Male" name="male" id="male" value="0">
<input type="radio" placeholder="Female" name="female" id="female" value="1">
```

Comment: Set them the same `name`

Comment: there are more than 2 genders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" placeholder="Male" name="gender" id="male" value="0">
<input type="radio" placeholder="Female" name="gender" id="female" value="1">
```

Give them the same `name` attribute.